# How to optimize script and handle dynamic data in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I need to create 12 months report, which counts values per months. I have made a separate temp table using WITH for each months which counts parts for each aircraft. It takes data from the PARTS table. My table for January looks like this:

| type | qty | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Airbus | 248 | 1 |
| Boeing | 120 | 1 |
| Emb | 14 | 1 |

Then I count amount of aicrafts each type per months using AC table, here's table for January:

| type | qty | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Airbus | 23 | 1 |
| Boeing | 10 | 1 |
| Emb | 5 | 1 |

Since I need to find a division of Qty to Count, I implement division Qty / count. So I joined table 1 and table 2 using month column.  And combined table for January looks like this:

| type | qty | count | div | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Airbus | 248 | 23 | 10.7 | 1 |
| Boeing | 120 | 10 | 12 | 1 |
| Emb | 14 | 5 | 2.8 | 1 |

I create temp table for each month and the combine them with UNION ALL. But I am afraid it could lead to DB slowdown. I think I need to rewrite and optimize my script. Any ideas how I could implement that?

Also the data in tables is dynamic and can change. So I need to look only for the last 12 months.

In my script I will have to manually add more months, which is not applicaple.

Is there a way that could possibly solve the problem of optimization and take into account only last 12 months?

Comment: What's the execution time of your script?

Comment: I strongly suggest you this reading : [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: The execution time is 3 seconds. But DBA suggested me to rewrite the script, since it could possibly lead to DB slowdown

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your table(s); the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; and the expected output. You appear to be only giving us the intermediate output from one of your `WITH` clauses rather than giving the source data which makes it very difficult to suggest how you can improve your query.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause for each month and trying to use `UNION ALL` to join them, you can include the month in the `GROUP BY` clause when you are counting the quantities in the `ac` and `part` table.

Since you only provided the intermediate output from the `WITH` clauses, I've had to try to reverse engineer your original tables to give a query something like this:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(ac.type, p.type) AS type,
       COALESCE(ac.month, p.month) AS month,
       COALESCE(ac.qty, 0) AS qty,
       COALESCE(p.qty, 0) AS count,
       CASE p.qty WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ac.qty / p.qty END AS div
FROM   (
         SELECT type,
                TRUNC(date_column, 'MM') AS month,
                COUNT(*) AS qty
         FROM   ac
         WHERE  date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
         GROUP BY
                type,
                TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
       ) ac
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT type,
                TRUNC(date_column, 'MM') AS month,
                COUNT(*) AS qty
         FROM   parts
         WHERE  date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
         GROUP BY
                type,
                TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
       ) p
       ON (
              ac.type  = p.type
          AND ac.month = p.month
          )
```